# Which version of Lollipop package should be installed on OS X with TeX Live Utility?

Tags: packages, texlive, mactex, mac, lollipop

I have installed basic TeX distribution (`basictex-20150613.pkg`) on my OS X 10.11.4. Now I want to install the `lollipop` package with `TeX Live Utility`. There is two options (I annotate them with red rectangles):

[image: TeX Live Utility screenshot]

Which version should be installed according to my OS?

Comment: The (pseudo)packages with the binaries should be automatically installed if you install the main `lollipop` package. Usually both versions of the binaries are installed; but in this case it makes no difference, because just two symbolic links are created.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Would you please write this solution as a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lollipop` package corresponds to a format (just like `latex` or `pdflatex`), so it is linked to the “binary” packages for the various platforms; the ones relative to the host machine are automatically installed.

[image]

On Mac OS X usually both `universal-darwin` and `x86_64-darwin` are installed (you can disable one of them, but it's not so space saving. In the particular case of a format like `lollipop` the binary packages just create a symbolic link, so just a few bytes in the file system.

You can see it with a shell command:

```bsh
> ls -l $(type -p lollipop)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 <user>  wheel  6 Jun 12  2015 /usr/texbin/lollipop@ -> pdftex
```

because this is how preloading the formats is implemented: the `pdftex` program knows the name it was called with and chooses the corresponding format.

---

A final comment: if you're not short of disk space, it's much better to install the full MacTeX (or TeX Live on other operating systems); life will be much easier, because manually installing packages with TeX Live Utility/`tlmgr` can be time consuming as there's no “dependency tree” available.